# can't print string with brackets in bash

Tags: bash

trying to print a string in a bash script, but it keeps unexepectedly changing on me.

```
$> /usr/local/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0)
```

Here is the same simple script three ways, only one doesn't work as I'd expect

will print `role[ba]`  **as expected**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

default="role[ba]"     
echo $default
exit 1
```

prints `roles` instead of `role[bas]` **not expected**?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

default="role[bas]"     
echo $default
exit 1
```

prints `role[foo]` **as expected**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

default="role[foo]"     
echo $default
exit 1
```

I don't know enough about bash, why can't I print the string w/ `role[bas]` in it?

Comment: Do you have a file `roles` in your current directory? If you don't quote the variable, it will expand to dirs/files names in your dir.

Comment: ah - you were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ touch roles
$ echo role[abc]
role[abc]
$ echo role[rst]
roles
$ echo role[foo]
```

`[]` is part of shell globbing syntax (character class). If you don't want globbing to happen, quote your variables. Same if you don't want word splitting. Essentially, always quote your variables *unless* you have a reason not to.

So:

```
echo "$default"
```